# Как настроить перенос строк в prettier?

Tags: html, prettier

Какой код я ввожу:

```html
<div class="header__holder header-info__holder">
  <a href="tel:+74991234567" class="header-info__phone-link">+7 499 123-45-67</a>
  <a href="mailto:aly-info@mail.ru" class="header-info__email-link">aly-info@mail.ru</a>
</div>
```

Как prettier форматирует код сейчас:

```html
<div class="header__holder header-info__holder">
  <a href="tel:+74991234567" class="header-info__phone-link"
    >+7 499 123-45-67</a
  >
  <a
    href="mailto:aly-info@mail.ru"
    class="header-info__email-link"
   >aly-info@mail.ru</a
  >
</div>
```

Как я ожидаю его форматирование:

```html
<div class="header__holder header-info__holder">
  <a href="tel:+74991234567" class="header-info__phone-link">
    +7 499 123-45-67
  </a>
  <a href="mailto:aly-info@mail.ru" class="header-info__email-link">
    aly-info@mail.ru
  </a>
</div>
```

настройки для prettier в vscode json

```js
"prettier.disableLanguages": ["javascript", "javascriptreact"],
"prettier.useTabs": true,
"[html]": {
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
},
```

Comment: почему бы изначально не писать код, так как ожидаете чтобы не было необходимости использовать утилиты для форматирования?

Comment: @teran, я через emmet получаю длинную строку, prettier ee форматирует, мне по 5 минут пробелы расставлять?

Comment: у вас написано "я ввожу".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема заключалась в рекомендуемой длине строки для prettier, из-за этого создавалось такое поведение.